# Rails get date to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, select

I would like to make something like show posts from a particular date.
I have

```
<% date =Date.parse('2014-06-18') %>
<% if feed_item_users.created_at < (date+1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') && feed_item_users.created_at > date %>
<li id="<%= feed_item_users.id %>">
  <span class="content"><%= wrap(feed_item_users.content) %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
     Published: <%= I18n.l feed_item_users.created_at, :format => :h %>
  </span>
</li>
<% end %>
```

in my view I'm checking date.
Now I would like to make a date_time select to get date from my web in format like '2014-06-18' and make default today date.
I know that it should look like that:

```
<%= form_for(??????) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :published_at %><br>
<%= f.datetime_select :published_at %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

but I don't know how to make it to variable because I need it only one time.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing dates against strings here which isn't reliable.  In your ruby code you should always compare dates against dates (or times).

Your logic seems to be "if created at is greater than the start of today and less than the start of tomorrow", which can be massively simplified to "if it's today".

ie you can replace this

```
<% date =Date.parse('2014-06-18') %>
<% if feed_item_users.created_at < (date+1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') && feed_item_users.created_at > date %>
```

with this

```
<% if feed_item_users.created_at.to_date == Date.today %>
```

The datetime_select is documented here 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Comment: I want to get date from my web, so if I change date to '2014-06-10' it will show my posts from '2014-06-10' - '2014-06-11'.
I only don't know how to get date to variable.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "from my web"?

Comment: I would like to make a field in my web application where I can get a date to my variable 'date'.

Comment: So, you want the user to input a date, submit a form, and then show posts that were created on that date?  Do you actually need to store what the user selects in the database?  If not then you already have the created_at field.  Also, you are talking about posts but your code has "feed_item_users" - what are they?

Answer (score 0):

strftime returns string so when you apply less then operator it doesn't work.

Better way is to do it like this:

```
time = Time.new(2014, 06, 18)
if feed_item_users.created_at > time.at_beginning_of_day && feed_item_users.created_at < (time+1.day).at_beginning_of_day
```